# Number of all possible ways of arranging N balls, M at a time in M boxes in cyclic fashion

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of $N$ types of balls out of which I want to pick $M$ at a time and arrange in $M$ boxes.

The conditions I have are
1. I am allowed to pick all $M$ balls of the same type. 
2. The boxes are arranged in a cycle. 
3. An additional constraint is that clockwise and anti-clockwise arrangements are considered to be equivalent.

In how many distinct ways this can be done? Any help is much appreciated.

I give some examples for simple cases.

1. $M$ = 5, $N$ = 1

   A  A  A  A  A
2. $M$ = 5, $N$ = 2

   A  A  A  A  A

   A  A  A  A  A

   A  A  A  A  B

   A  A  A  B  B

   A  A  B  A  B

   A  A  B  B  B

   A  B  A  B  B

   B  B  B  B  A

   B  B  B  B  B

Note that in the second example the arrangements A A A B B and B B A A A are considered equivalent hence only A A A B B is given. Also other cyclic permutations are ignored.

On the other hand A A A B B and A A B A B are considered distinct because they are not related by cyclic permutations.

Comment: "A A B A B, and A B A B A are considered distinct because they are not related by cyclic permutations." AABAB -> [A]ABAB -> ABAB[A] -> ABABA?

Comment: @sharkos: Thanks for rightly point it out. I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

- If you only have $M$ boxes without the cycle, this is given by the set of words of length $M$ on $N$ letters. There are $N^M$ such words.
- Now, let's assume the equivalence up to cycles. In the combinatorics literature, these are called "necklaces," and you can find out more about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29).
- If you also want the equivalence up to reflection, see "bracelets" or "turnover necklaces" on the same Wikipedia page.

Comment: great! thanx for the details.

Comment: You're welcome!